# Python mypy Type Hinting shutil.copyfileobj() has incompatible type "Union[HTTPResponse, BinaryIO]"; expected IO[Any]

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm getting the following mypy error for the code below.  How can I properly cast the response object so that mypy is happy with me passing it to the shutil.copyfileobj method?

`error:Argument 1 to "copyfileobj" has incompatible type "Union[HTTPResponse, BinaryIO]"; expected IO[Any]`

The following code streams the response from a web request to a file.

```
request = urllib.request.Request(get_file_url, headers=self.data_api_headers)

with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
    with open(export_file_path, 'wb') as out_file:

        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [a bug in typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/2189#event-1676741668)

the `HTTPResponse` stub didn't extend from `BinaryIO` and therefore wasn't considered a candidate for functions taking `IO[bytes]` -- this has been fixed

This fix should land in the next release of `mypy` (should be `0.620` if I'm guessing their version scheme correctly).  Alternatively, you can run `mypy` with `--custom-typeshed-dir` to get the changes sooner